# Order topology on non discrete set

Tags: general-topology

Set $X=\{1,2\} \times\mathbb Z^+$ where $\mathbb Z^+$ is positive intergers. Consider $X$ under dictionary order. The order topology on $X$ is not discrete. Why it is not discrete here? Why I cannot use $\{1,2\}\times[a,b)$ form to get a basis?

Comment: The space $\{1,2\}\times\textbf{Z}_+$ is not discrete because the singleton $\{(2,1)\}$ is not open. Do you see why?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734376/show-that-the-lexicographic-order-topology-for-mathbbn-times-mathbbn-is

Comment: And also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638064/order-topology-on-the-set-x-1-2-times-mathbbz